# getting IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc

HI i am getting the below error while trying to login to my application. i am using websphere7, java7, oracle11g with eclipse juno.

the error i got is as below.

[4/9/15 16:46:23:327 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
[4/9/15 16:46:23:328 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
[4/9/15 16:46:23:328 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
[4/9/15 16:46:23:328 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:236)
[4/9/15 16:46:23:328 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
[4/9/15 16:46:23:328 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
[4/9/15 16:46:23:328 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O  at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
[4/9/15 16:46:23:329 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O  at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:207)
[4/9/15 16:46:23:331 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O  at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:139)
[4/9/15 16:46:23:331 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O  at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:88)

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of reason why the connection between 2 systems fails. The first question that you should ask are:

- does it happen every time?
- does it happen intermittently? If it is intermittent, can you identify any commonality in the failure? Is it always for one user? is it always at a certain time? and so on.
- Can you do a ping to access the remote server?
- Can you do a telent to access the remote service?

Finally, in all cases where connection problem arise, the best way to investigate it is to use a packet sniffing tool (personally, I like wireshark). This will give you information on what is actually happening on the wire.